# Tourist activities in the Louisiana bayou swamp area with the recent floods?

Tags: usa, event-based-effects, water-sports, natural-disasters, louisiana

I am planning a trip (in November!) to Louisiana and we would like to explore some of the swamp/bayou area in Louisiana. Currently we are thinking of Breaux Bridge exactly. A Texan friend advised against going there, because he said the recent floods would have destroyed everything and you wouldn't be able to enjoy nature there anymore.

We are thinking of things like kayaking, swamp tours, just walking around and just eating good food. All in all a relaxed couple of days, nothing special.

Is the damage as bad as my friend says? Are the activities I am interested in available/open at the moment as normal, or are there partial/total closures?

Comment: We wouldn't give a go/no-go advice (that is opinion based). I'm sure somebody can comment on the availability of nature tours and restraunts however.

Comment: @CMaster I'm new here, so advice like 'The place is flooded so I wouldn't go' would not be okay either? That is an opinion based on facts I guess? I don't know. But thanks!

Comment: "This place is flooded. These things you want to do are shut" Would be fine. Asking for an opinion/judgement call is a way to get a question closed (because we end up just having lots of opinions, and a popularity contest). I'm going to edit your question to make it a better fit for the site (note that your Q hasn't led to anyone placing a close vote yet) as an example.

Comment: @CMaster Thanks for the explanation, I will keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check with [St. Martin Parish Tourist Commission](http://www.cajuncountry.org/contact.php) and see if there any issues upon arriving.

In October 7 there is a [Tour Du Teche Kayak race](http://www.tourduteche.com/), and in [News](http://www.cajuncountry.org/contact.php) section you can see that there are festivals that will take place around November-December 2016.

Adding to @Johns-305 the bayou does flood every year and they have systems to clear out the water and restore the water level. Also, November is part of the dry season, and there is almost no rain.

Breaux Bridge have several lovely sites to see, I lived in Baton Rouge for several years and it was one our favorite weekend getaways.

Just a lagniappe (little something extra): Cafe Des Amis. You **must** arrive at Saturday morning. They have [Zydeco Breakfast with live Band](http://cafedesamis.com/). Make sure you stand at the door as early as 7:30AM to get in.

Answer (score 3):

Consider that, ecologically, the bayou flooding is not uncommon.  Really, flooding is what makes it a bayou in the first place so a flood certainly can't destroy a swamp.

The Breaux Bridge city web site or tourism Facebook give no indication flood issues.  You can always call them with any questions.

I wouldn't let the recent event affect a trip 4 months away.